# Filter for elements using exists through a reverse foreign key relationship

Tags: django, orm

A relevant image of my model is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzsVU.png

I need to make a queryset that contains all cats who have an associated person with a role of "owner" and a name of "bob".

The sql for this would be shown below.

```
select * from cat where exists 
(select 1 from person inner join role where 
person.name="bob" and role.name="owner");
```

This problem can be solved in two sql queries with the following django filters.

```
people = Person.objects.filter(name="bob", role__name="owner")
ids = [p.id for p in people]
cats = Cat.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

My actual setup is more complex than this and is dealing with a large dataset. Is there a way to do this with one query? If it is impossible, what is the efficient alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is your query:

```
cats = Cat.objects.filter(person__name='bob', person__role__name='owner')
```

read here about [**`look ups spanning relationships`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Wouldn't that find a cat that has a vet named Bob and an owner who was named George? I need to have both be true on a single Person who has the cat in question.

Comment: I'm think that filter statements are `AND`ed unless using `Q`.